# iOS 7 UIPopoverController with strange border

Tags: ios, ios7, uipopovercontroller

Something strange happen with some iOS 7 UIPopoverController : borders appears on a side of the popup. Here is a screenshot :

[image]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/440274Capturedcran20140414224144.png))</sub>

Here is my code to open the popup.

```
// .h
@property(nonatomic, retain) InAppPurchaseViewController *inAppPurchaseViewController;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController* inappPurchasePopover;

// .m
if (!self.inappPurchasePopover) {
    self.inAppPurchaseViewController = [[InAppPurchaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InAppPurchaseViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.inAppPurchaseViewController.settingsViewController = self;
    self.inAppPurchaseViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.inAppPurchaseViewController.view.frame.size;
    self.inappPurchasePopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.inAppPurchaseViewController];
    self.inappPurchasePopover.delegate = self;
    self.inappPurchasePopover.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.view.subviews];
}

// On affiche
[self.inappPurchasePopover presentPopoverFromRect:delegateAppli.principalNavigationController.topViewController.view.frame inView:delegateAppli.principalNavigationController.topViewController.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

Everything works fine in iOS 6.

Comment: The screenshot is far too small to see whatever it is that you circled.

Comment: check out [revealapp](http://revealapp.com), which is a neat tool to analyze the view hierarchy.